# Rally, Infopath, and SharePoint

Tags: rally

I am trying to pull a list of user stories for any project using infopath. 
I am able to connect to the source https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.31/subscription?stylesheet=/slm/doc/webservice/browser.xsl but am not able to pull anything meaningful from it
at all. Can someone help me?

Its a very easy thing to do with other data sources, such as with active directory:
http://kwizcom.blogspot.com/2007/11/importing-data-from-ad-to-infopath-2007.html

If you can help steer me towards finding just a list of user stories, I’d appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

What format would you like the data in?

Json:
    https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.31/hierarchicalrequirement.js

Xml:
    https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.31/hierarchicalrequirement.xml

All the objects exposed in the Web Services API have similar endpoints and query parameters.

Here is an example to pull back all stories that are in progress:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.31/hierarchicalrequirement.js?query=(ScheduleState = "In-Progress")&fetch=Name,Owner,PlaneEstimate
```

You can test out other queries in the live web service docs as well:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/

Comment: If I put anything in the path with a "?" or an "=", etc, it doesnt work. If I try the xml file, it will let me connect to the data source but I still cant pull any meaningful data. Im just trying to pull a list of anything from any of the available parts into a repeating table. I always either get nothing or just one obscure item. I'd add a screenshot, but it wont let me.

Comment: Nevermind, I was doing it wrong. I was adding the repeating table, and then trying to set the default value. Cant do it that way. Have to pull up the data source, then drag and drop the object item under results over to the area you want it, then it will ask you what format, at that point select repeating table. Now I get the list I was looking for!

Comment: I have a new issue though, I am now only able to produce a limit of 20 items. I have a drop down list set to pull releases, but I only get 20 to choose from every time. This happens sometimes in a sharepoint list when the default view is only set to show a certain amount. Is there a Rally equivalent to that?

Comment: Include a pageSize=200 parameter in your url.  By default WSAPI results are limited to 20.  200 is the max.  After that you'll have to page through the results using the start parameter.  (I'm not super familiar with InfoPath, so I'm not sure if that's possible or not)

Comment: I was successfully able to pull the user stories I wanted into an infopath dropdown using this: https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.31/hierarchicalrequirement?query=((Name contains "release") and (ScheduleState = In-Progress))&order=CreationDate desc&fetch=true&pagesize=200&PortfolioItem=Bedford Operations&stylesheet=/slm/doc/webservice/browser.xsl   Now I am going to see about getting a Description of the user story that doesnt show all of the html coding. If anyone knows anything about filtering that out, I'd surely appreciate it!